# Flask app on Azure gives 400 error code for POST request

Tags: python, azure, http, flask, post

I am sending an HTTP Post request to the route called `/replace` in my Flask app.

When run locally, `/replace` gives me a `200` response (OK), but when I deploy the Flask app to Azure Web Apps, I receive a `400` error (Bad request).

However, when I try to call a GET request to a route called `/`, the app on Azure Web Apps gives me a `200` response (OK).

Why does Azure throw a `400` (Bad request) response on Azure Web Apps for a `POST` request, while the same Flask app run locally gives a `200` (OK response) for the same `POST` request?

**Flask app server:**

```py
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

result = {}

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    return "home"

@app.route("/replace", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def override_result_dict():
    global result
    json = request.get_json(force=True)
    result = json
    return "replaced", 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

**POST Request**

```py
import requests
r = requests.post("<URL>/replace", json={1:1})
```

The Azure Web App configuration:

- Python 3.7
- HTTP version: 2.0
- Web sockets: off
- Client certificate mode: ignore
- FTP state: allowed

Comment: what do you get on flask's console? also, dont you need to import the request as well?: `from flask import Flask, request`

Comment: @ilias-sp I made a typo in my post, I do indeed have `from flask import Flask, request`

Comment: OK, you need to check Flask's console to understand what is going on with that request. on my PC, your flow works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

The Azure web app converted all `POST` requests into `GET` requests. As a result, this unintended conversion likely threw a `400` error because `POST` and `GET` are incompatible.

The solution was to send a POST request with `https` instead of `http` at the start of the URL.

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/68569613-74d3-4e5a-ae30-d5253a536c0c/post-request-turns-into-get?forum=AzureAPIApps